# Ninject Xamarin.Forms Exception While Instantiating StandardKernel

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, ninject, .net-standard-2.0

I'm getting an exception when trying to build my Ninject instance:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Error loading Ninject component IBindingPrecedenceComparer
No constructor was available to create an instance of the registered implementation type BindingPrecedenceComparer.
```

I tried to instantiate it like explained in their docs:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
```

and like this:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false });
```

I'm using Xamarin Forms, .NET Standard 2.0 and Android 8.0

**UPDATE**

I have found that this is caused when a .NET Standard project is referenced from your Xamarin.Forms project (also .NET Standard) and the referenced project has **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** installed.